# Magento 2: Checkout page error Failed to load the "ui/form/element/" template

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am getting error on checkout, I have remove all extension and try if this is cause of extensions but no luck.

```
[ERROR] Failed to load the "ui/form/element/" template requested by "checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.depotid".
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `depotid` is not default in magento shipping. Looks like some custom extension has added it. Please deploy static content again and try again. Please check DB tables as well once to see if this field is somewhere in quote, sales tables.

Comment: Should I disable all extensions to see this error stability?

Comment: Disable only those extensions which are linked with checkout module and then trym

Comment: I tried remove all extensions and clean and refresh cache , but issue is still there

Comment: clean "generated" folder once and run di:compile and then run content deployment and try once. Check if this field is somewhere in DB

Comment: I remove Generated and again compile but no luck

Comment: depotid not find in any file as well as in database tables

Comment: Try finding this "depotid" in whole project once and see any reference.

Comment: I found this in 'eav_attribute' table with attibute code 153 but it's not found in store->attribute

Comment: can you delete it and then try once? Once it will work, then we can think for adding this back.

Comment: Yea I found and deleted the depotid and postcodeid from database then error gone. 
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add thumbs up if it help. :) . Now you can put your modules back can can check which module will cause this issue.